# Why do some Win API constants have alternative names?

Tags: windows, winapi

According to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox page, it seems that some constants have alternative names.

```
To display an icon in the message box, specify one of the following values:

Names              | Value       | Description
-------------------|-------------|--------------------------------
MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | 0x00000030L | An exclamation-point
MB_ICONWARNING     |             |
-------------------|-------------|---------------------------------
MB_ICONINFORMATION | 0x00000040L | A lowercase letter i in a circle
MB_ICONASTERISK    |             |
-------------------|-------------|---------------------------------
MB_ICONSTOP        | 0x00000010L | A stop-sign
MB_ICONERROR       |             |
MB_ICONHAND        |             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the reason for such a decision?

*Edit; not a part of the question, just a sidenote:* I would suggest to use `MB_ICONWARNING`, `MB_ICONINFORMATION`, and `MB_ICONERROR` since they are generic ones and not descriptions of the specific images. Images may differ from one version of Windows to another, and so they aren't very "reliable".

Comment: Hans Passant or Raymond Chen might be able to address this, but I guess the answer will be backwards compatibility by leaving in the older names when coming up with new ones. "Warning" is a more generic term than "Exclamation", and who knows, the warning icon can be replaced with something that isn't an exclamation mark.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, this is the most likely reason. Though in such a case Microsoft could arrange these names in a more logical way. `MB_ICONWARNING` should be located above and not below `MB_ICONEXCLAMATION`. And the similar rearrangement for `MB_ICONERROR`, probably.

Comment: What would be the benefit of rearranging the symbols? None, as far as I can tell. What would be the risk of rearranging the symbols? It's almost guaranteed that you're breaking someone's build. Over time, given enough users, **every** observable aspect becomes a feature people will start to rely upon.

Comment: For example `MB_ICONEXCLAMATION` was the constant originally defined in the 16-bit Windows 3.x SDKs. The `MB_ICONWARNING` "alias" was added in the Windows 95 SDK, and is still defined inside an `#if(WINVER >= 0x0400)` block in `winUser.h` to this day. So, yes, it's a matter of backwards compatibility.